# How to get page www.facebook... for my apps.facebook...?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have my app up and running via:

> http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=103297833078853

Now I want to claim a page such as `http://www.facebook.com/mycyberspaceapp`

Can you tell me how? I want the page `http://www.facebook.com/mycyberspaceapp` to lead to

> my http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=103297833078853

...where I can click "Go to App"

**Update:**

I still can't do it. It says:

> This page needs more fans Before you can set your username for your
>   page, your page needs more fans.

But my app has 32 likes; is that not enough?

Comment: Direct link was http://www.facebook.com/username/ where it clearly says that may pages are "not eligible" and can have a username in the future.

Comment: This is not a catch-22. Your app is still available at http://apps.facebook.com/cyberfaze/ you can definitely promote that.

Comment: There is also 1 monthly active user, I doubt this qualifies one for a username.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting the name is not enough for your apps. You'll end up at `http://apps.facebook.com/<yourappname>`

You can get the alias (`http://www.facebook.com/<yourapp>`) only if enough people "like" it (I think the minimum is 25 people). Works the same way for FB pages, I think.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Facebook page : [Click Here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php)

Select the category that suits your application, than fill up the details and change the security settings accordingly after login in to your account. Fill up the details as you wish. You can control this page from your account directly,

Now to make a page address like http://www.facebook.com/mycyberspaceapp go to settings, in the basic info section, change the name and desired username you want for your page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that I need a so-called username to get the alias and going to the settings you mention I see a `Your page needs at least 25 fans to have a username.`

Comment: You welcome :) & thanks for that information, I'll check that out :)

Answer (score 2):

That's easy,

1. Login to your actual account switch your account to Page.
2. On the right hand-corner: **Edit Page**
3. Click on **Basic Information**.
4. On line 4: Choose a name that you want your Fans page going to be like the above.

Comment: THen it says "Before you can set your username for your page, your page needs more fans." and it still is not connecting to my app, it is the page and not the app